# What happens with http servlet when request times out?

Tags: java, servlets

I have heavy, time consuming logic called from http servlet. What happens when request times out? Will servlet container suspend underlying http thread? Or it will keep running?

Comment: I think it should keep running.  To try it out, write an HttpServlet that just goes into an infinite loop.  Attach a debugger to figure out what happens to that thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will keep running unaware that the client that requested the request might be long gone.

## ThreadPools

An application server usually houses a bounded [ThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/perform/appb_queues.html) to serve requests. These pools are available per web app or can even be targeted be servlet / EJB. When you run a thread for prolonged periods of time (or forever), it utilizes a Thread from the pool and never returns that resource until it is done. This can cause the thread pool to reach its maximum size and eventually degrade the performance of calls made to the web app.

There is also the concept of an **unbounded thread pool** where the max number of threads that can be consumed by the pool is only limited by the hardware. That can be a bad idea for 'quality of service' attributes defined by the server since unbounded pools can affect the entire machine and not just the WAR / code causing the problem.

## Stuck threads

Some application servers have provisions to detect this and mark such threads as [STUCK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/WLSTuning.html). There are JMX apis that can kill the threads or you can nuke the WAR to get the threads to be released back into a pool.

## Timeouts

Timeouts apply to the HTTP layer and not the server side. Thee are various HTTP timeouts such as.

- **Connection timeout** - Time taken to establish connection.
- **Read timeout** - Timeout that occurs because the client took too long to read a response.
- <s>**SO Timeout** - Socket timeout for the entire operation.</s>

The servlet is unaware of these. When writing to a closed connection you should see errors such as - `Connection close by remote host`

Want to avoid all this ? Write a servlet that processes your request quickly and returns ASAP. That'll keep your throughput high and users happy.

Comment: There is no such thing as 'SO timeout - Socket timeout for the entire operation'. There are connect timeouts and read timeouts, nothing else.

Comment: @EJP I've had to redefine my understanding of an underlying SO timeout  after researching your comment. I always thought read timeouts were more fine grained. I'll edit the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I hope that by 'redefine my understanding' you really mean 'check my *facts* instead of making things up.' There are further inventions here. The remaining timeouts, the ones that actually exist, are at the TCP level, not the HTTP level, and they apply to both sides. 'Errors such as "connection closed by remote host"' is another figment of your imagination. I hope you meant 'connection reset by peer', but you could always get it right first time. And the entire digression about thread pools really has nothing to do with it.

Comment: The remaining timeouts can be set for the HTTP connection. I was not implying that they _belong_ to HTTP. I don't see why connections being forcibly closed are a figment of my imagination when they happen in reality. By re-define my understanding I meant that my understanding of the SO-Timeout setting was initially incorrect until I read your comment and researched it again. Your allegation that I 'make things up' is amusing at best and leaves no room to consider that I might be correcting an honest mistake. The Thread pools are not a digression. The OP wants to know what happens to them.

Answer (score 2):

The servlet thread is still running,because timed out is a client behaviour,the only effect is client close the inputstream of the request(outputstream of servlet),the results may not be sent to the client.

Comment: I think that timeout is servlet container specific. Once it's reached servet usually sends something like HTTP Error 408 Request timeout. I'm not asking what happens when timeout occurs because of bad connectivity, etc.

Comment: http request timeout is specified by the clients.